# Nested foreach loop slow

Tags: c#, optimization, foreach

The following piece of code achives the desired results, but performance is extremely slow:

```
SearchResultCollection absaUsers = ABSAds.FindAll();
SearchResultCollection srcUsers = ds.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult users in srcUsers)
{
    string cn = users.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
    string sn = users.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
    string userID = users.Properties["uid"][0].ToString();
    string description = users.Properties["PersonnelAreaDesc"][0].ToString();
    string jobCodeID = users.Properties["JobcodeID"][0].ToString();
    string CostCentreID = users.Properties["costCentreID"][0].ToString();
    string CostCentreDescription = users.Properties["CostCentreDescription"][0].ToString();
    string givenName = users.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
    string employmentStatus = users.Properties["EmploymentStatus"][0].ToString();
    string EmploymentStatusDescription = users.Properties["EmploymentStatusDescription"][0].ToString();

    foreach (SearchResult absaUser in absaUsers)
    {

        string absaUID = absaUser.Properties["uid"][0].ToString();
        string absaEmploymentStatus = absaUser.Properties["EmploymentStatus"][0].ToString();
        string absaEmploymentStatusDescription = absaUser.Properties["EmploymentStatusDescription"][0].ToString();
        string absaEmployeeNumber = absaUser.Properties["employeeNumber"][0].ToString();

        if (absaUID == cn && absaEmployeeNumber==userID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User Record Found:" + cn);
            sw.WriteLine("Modify" + "," + cn + "," + description + "," + userID + "," + givenName + "," + sn + "," + jobCodeID + "," + CostCentreID + "," + CostCentreDescription + "," + sn + "," + cn + "," + employmentStatus + "," + EmploymentStatusDescription);
            sw.Flush();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It loops through 2 collections and mtaches the outer loops attributes with the inner's. Any suggestions on how I can optimise the performance?

Comment: Any statistics on performance measurements? How many items in the lists `absaUsers` and `srcUsers`?

Comment: If this all come from database, you better do it in the SQL level and Join the tables, fetching only the data you need..

Comment: Sorry for not being very specific. This program connects 2 different LDAP Stores, and compares user attributes. absaUsers contain about 50 000 users and scrUsers contain about 11 000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be faster if you extracted all the `absaUID` values to a lookup first:

```
var lookup = absaUsers.Cast<SearchResult>()
                      .ToLookup(x => x.Properties["uid"][0].ToString());
```

Then you can just use:

```
foreach (SearchResult users in srcUsers)
{
    string cn = users.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
    foreach (SearchResult matches in lookup[cn])
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You haven't shown how `absaUsers` is defined - if it's a LINQ query expression, then it could be that your existing code will be going to the database on every iteration at the moment - whereas the above won't. On the other hand, if `srcUsers` is *also* a LINQ query expression talking to a database, you should consider doing all the matching at the database using a join instead.

Comment: @Trishen: You'll probably need a call to `Cast` - will add that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use LINQ join, some examples are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746), I'm assuming whoever built it into .NET found a pretty optimal way of doing that, and then loop through that. on a sidenote: what are your collection types? please add their declaration to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lamda expressions:

Below is the sample one , You can optizime this to another level.

```
    List<SearchResult> allResultGroups=new  List<SearchResult>();
    foreach (SearchResult absaUser in absaUsers)
    {
    resultGroups = srcUsers.Where(g => g.cn == absaUser.absaUID && absaUser.absaEmployeeNumber==g.userID ).ToList();
    }
```